# How can I avoid sites that scrape and republish others?

Tags: google-search

Usually I use Google for search. Over the last few months most of the top search results I get are for sites that only seem to exist to scrape others. For example these ones scrape Microsoft's forums: [Go4Answers](http://www.go4answers.com/), [MSDN.iTags.Org](http://msdn.itags.org/), [Tech-Archive](http://www.tech-archive.net/), etc...

I only ever want to see the **source content** in search results and never want to see these types of sites.

[Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) and its filtering options looked good initially but the results page lacks so many of the features of the standard Google search engine, I've found myself avoiding it.

Is there a good way to banish these types of sites?

Comment: I just discovered the feature used in my answer a few weeks ago and tech-archive was the first site I blocked. I hate that site with a passion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search for product reviews without junk sites](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/how-to-search-for-product-reviews-without-junk-sites)

Answer (score 6):

Add a star to the results that come from the site that you like. Over time Google should favour results from those sites.

Not a bulletproof solution, but you should start getting more personalized results.

Answer (score 3):

**Block the site from the search results**

Just login to your account and then go to [Manage Blocked Sites](http://www.google.com/reviews/t), there you can add the domain of the offending site (remember to include the `http://` prefix).

Example:

```
http://blogs.technet.com
http://technet.microsoft.com
http://mobile.experts-exchange.com
http://experts-exchange.com
```

All the pages within the blocked sites will be blocked, so you don't need to add subdomains.

Note: Google allows you to block up to 500 sites.

Comment: Technet gets their honorary mention today because I just read a blog article on their site that exceeded my FUD threshold for the year. Experts-exchange OTOH shouldn't need (or deserve) an explanation as to why it's blocked.

Comment: OMG. That's the solution I've looked for years! Thank you so very much!

Comment: @Basilevs lol, I'm glad I could help.