# How to search for product reviews without junk sites

Tags: search

When using a search engine to look for <product xyz> reviews, tons of useless sites are returned that don't give real product feedback.

**Is there any way to search for 3rd party information on a product while**

**Excluding:**
   Fake news sites
   Astroturfing sites
   Places that sell the product (unless they have useful reviews)

**Including:**
   Legitimate review sites and blogs
   Sites like stack exchange
   Legit discussion forums

One example is searching for reviews on a fat camp called "Camp Technique".  The first 50 Google results are mostly useless.  Even if no useful feedback sites exists for this company, shouldn't it be easier to know there is nothing useful?

The bottom line is how to find 3rd party product information with the best signal to noise ratio and less junk sites.

Comment: +1 Google itself is trying hard to keep the junk out. Figuring out what is junk is a challenge, as owners of once legitimate places often start monetizing their investments, and astroturfers do their best to look credible and cultivate incoming links. A crowdsourcing+search engine approach might be the best approach, Google tried that a few years ago (you could +1 or -1 each result of a search) but they stopped, not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Block the offending sites from Google search**

If you have a Google account you can sign up for one either by creating a Gmail account at [mail.google.com](https://mail.google.com) or by creating a Google account using an existing email at [accounts.google.com](https://accounts.google.com).

Once you have an account, go to your [dashboard](https://www.google.com/dashboard/).

There's a section called blocked sites. Enter the site's domain name (including `http://`) to block all results from that specific site.

It blocks on the domain level, so you may need to put in multiple entries for a site.

Ex:

```
http://blogs.technet.com
http://technet.microsoft.com
http://mobile.experts-exchange.com
http://experts-exchange.com
```

That should help you eliminate the worst offenders. Enjoy...

*Note: I don't have the link to reference but I'm pretty sure that Google allows a max of 500 sites that you can block from the search results.*

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome browser and there is a plug in that allows you to block such sites. When you see a search result that is bogus, you can click it in the Google search return page to block it. It takes some time to build the list but aver time works well.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef

How it works with screenshots
http://rcayao.com/internet/google-chrome-launches-personal-blocklist/

Comment: I have previously tried that, but unfortunately the list constantly varies.  So this approach can help if you repeatedly search for similar items, but in practice there is a never ending list of different searches.  For example one week a doctor, next week a printer, next week a baseball glove, an so on for the rest of our lives.